# Counting the total number of commits a user has made in a subversion repo

Tags: svn

I'd like to produce a list of users and their total commits to a subversion repository. Is it possible to generate this information from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this:
http://blogs.oracle.com/mikey/entry/count_svn_commits_for_each

Comment: Thanks, missed your post before posting another link I found, that's great, cheers!

Comment: Much easier than fiddling with http://www.statsvn.org/ if the count is all you need. =)

Comment: Link is dead (September 2017)